# How to write basic titles for your assignments in Chinese? (such as "[Topic] Reflection")

Tags: translation

Often when I have a simple assignment that involves answering a few questions, I'll title the page with something like this:

> "[Topic] Questions" or "[Topic] Reflection"

How would you do that in Chinese? Let's say the assignment was a reflection on a group activity you recently completed. In English I'd write something like "Reflection on Last Week's Group Activity." (I mean, that's super boring, but sometimes you've just got to get the job done!)

Comment: s。ichacha 回顾：look back; review; retrospect
短语和例子 e。g。回顾上星期（周）小组的活动（w/o 的： 小组 would be more closely linked to 活动: 小组活动: group session)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reflection) dictionary, *'reflections on'* means:

> **Reflections on something** are comments or writings that express
>   someone's ideas about it.

Reflection here is like 评论 in formal writing.

> Reflection on Last Week's Group Activity: 关于上星期集体活动的评论

Answer (score 1):

In that case, the title usually is 'xx感想 or xx有感'

'上周活动有感', '集体活动的感受' or '小组活动的感想'

There are some typical titles for reading and watching, <双城记>读后感, <超人>观后感

Those are the equivalent boring titles in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I am a great believer in 'less is more', so I like what Jacob wrote best. Just as alternatives I would proffer:

上周小组活动的反馈
上周小组活动的反思与检讨

反馈：response, feedback
反思与检讨: review and retrospection (‘what could we have done better?’)

Comment: A side question: How should we understand "Reflection on Last Week's Group Activity" In English?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I forgot to answer: 'reflect on something' just means 'think about something' so "Reflection on Last Week's Group Activity" could also be called 'My/Our thoughts about last week's group activity." It is perfectly correct and acceptable.